# Get total length of all lists inside a map of tuples

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, flat

I am working on a Scala project and I have a Map of type `Map[Long, Tuple2[Boolean, List[Int]]]`.

I need to assign the total number of elements in all lists within the map to a variable.

I currently have a working solution, however, I want a more efficient solution. I am sure I have heard people say that you can use something called `flatMap`. So essentially, I want to know if there is a solution that doesn't require a loop, where I can say ***add the length of all lists in the map***.

My solution was as follows:

```
for((k, v) <- myMap) total = total + v._2.length
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of efficiency, your execution would always be `O(n)` in your map.

If you want to use a more declarative approach, you can use `foldLeft`:

```
val total = myMap.foldLeft(0) {
  case (total, (_, list)) => total + list.length
}
```

`foldLeft` takes a seed as it's first parameter list, which we can initialize to `0`. And then we iterate through each one of the lists, summing them up and returning the intermediate result. When we reach the end of the key value pair, the last accumulated element will be returned as the result.

Comment: It is actually `O(keys*average_list_length)`, not just `O(keys)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make your code more efficient, the problem is **O(N)** by definition.

However, if the `Map` is very big you may parallelize the code. You may also use a different data type other than `List` that doesn't need to iterate itself to compute its length.

Finally, proposing another way of getting rid of mutability.

```scala
val total =
  myMap
    .valuesIterator
    .map(_._2.length)
    .sum
```